# LibCST: Converting arbitrary nodes to code

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, libcst

Is it possible to dump an arbitrary LibCST node into Python code? My use case is that I want to extract the code for functions that match a specific naming scheme. I can extract the `FunctionDef` nodes that I need, but I don't seem to find a way to convert them to code.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible using the method [`code_for_node`](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodes.html#libcst.Module.code_for_node) from the `Module` class.

You use it as follow:

```
import libcst

function_def = libcst.parse_statement("def hello_world():\n  print('Hello World')")
print(libcst.Module([]).code_for_node(function_def))
```

and that would generate the output:

```
def hello_world():
    print('Hello World')
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Note this does not work for every code object within LibCST, for example it does not work on `Annotation`. However, it does work on the `Param` object that contains that same `Annotation`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77379845/7437143) is a full description of this example.